# Debugging JavaScript files in Sublime Text 2 with Xdebug plugin

Tags: sublimetext2

I am a newbie as far as debugging goes. I usually just see if my javascript works and if not just start searching through my code. Can someone give me a walk through for dummies of how to set a breakpoint and see if the page hits it using Sublime Text?

I am using Xdebug for Sublime Text.
https://github.com/martomo/SublimeTextXdebug#breakpoints

Comment: XDebug is for PHP. Not Javascript. You have to debug this in the browser.

Comment: @DaGardner yeah but how? How do you set a breakpoint that will be picked up in your browser and then step through?